# Cannot add having condition on undefined result variable in a non aggregated query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm executing this query in an entity repository and keep getting

> Cannot add having condition on undefined result variable

but the query has no aggregation at all. Why is this happening to me?

```
public function getPersonalizableItemsByOwner(User $owner)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT pi FROM '.$this->getEntityName().' pi WHERE order_id = :owner_id AND (deletedAt IS NULL OR deletedAt > :referenceDate)')
        ->setParameters(array('owner_id' => $owner->getId(), 'referenceDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

        return $qb->getResult();
}
```

PS: I have very little knowledge of Doctrine, i'm tasked to add soft delete support through KnpLabs SoftDeleteable trait but only in some specific situation, thus i can't use a globally available filter and must implement it manually.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the error, but you should prefix your column names with `pi` as you've aliased the table to that e.g. `pi.order_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in the DQL, the field was supposed to be ownerId and not order_id. Further more, the the namespace of each field needs to be provided it seems such as:

```
public function getPersonalizableItemsByOwner(User $owner)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT pi FROM '.$this->getEntityName().' pi WHERE pi.ownerId = :owner_id AND (pi.deletedAt IS NULL OR pi.deletedAt > :referenceDate)')
        ->setParameters(array('owner_id' => $owner->getId(), 'referenceDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You must not check for deletedAt to be null but check if deletedAt's ID to be null.

Changing to : `deletedAt.id IS NULL` should fix it.

edit : Got this error this morning and fixed it thanks to : http://www.christophe-meneses.fr/article/corriger-l-erreur-request-critical-uncaught-php-exception-doctrine-orm-query-queryexception-semantical-error-cannot-add-having-condition-on-a-non-result-variable