# Doctrine select entities with relation condition

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Given two tables:

**notification**

```
id               (int PK)
title            (varchar(255))
date             (datetime)
```

**notification_seen**

```
id               (int PK)
notification_id  (int FK)
user_id          (int FK)
```

**user**

```
id               (int PK)
```

mapped as simple Doctrine entities where **Notification** has a relation defined as follows:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NotificationSeen", mappedBy="notification")
private $seenBy;
```

and **NotificationSeen**:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Notification", inversedBy="seenBy")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="notification_id")
private $notification;

@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="seen")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private $user;
```

and **User** entity:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NotificationSeen", mappedBy="users")
private $seen;
```

I want to select all **Notification** objects which are **not** connected through the *seenBy* relation.

How to select such entities in the NotificationRepository with the QueryBuilder? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Current method implementation in the **NotificationRepository**:

```
public function getUnreadNotification(User $user): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orderBy('u.date', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: If there is no notificationSeen between user and notification, how can you find any notification? There is any other links between a user and a notification that are not exposed in your post? Or you mean that you want to create a new notificationSeen relationship?

Comment: I want to select those entities through the Notification repository, not through the User entity. So to speak I need to select all entities from the notification table that don't exists in the notification_seen table for the specified user.

Comment: Can we have a look at the code you've tried? the query builder part?

Comment: Well I added what I got, which is essentially nothing.

Comment: The Notification has no direct relation to User except through NotificationSeen, how do you expect to implement a join in the db if there is NotificationSeen to join the other two tables?

Comment: Ok lets assume I connected the NotificationSeen with the User (schema above have been updated). Does this change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just want to query the db for `Notifications` that have no related `NotificationSeen`:

```
public function getUnreadNotification(User $user): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->join('n.seenBy', 'ns')
        ->where('ns.id IS NULL')
        ->orderBy('n.created', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: "Error: Cannot add having condition on a non result variable"

Comment: I updated my answer, please do double check you are using my most updated code.

Comment: Ok well look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378208/cannot-add-having-condition-on-undefined-result-variable-in-a-non-aggregated-que. Change `ns IS NULL` to `ns.id IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarification – the thing I wanted is called RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposal for Mike's comment

> [...] So to speak I need to select all entities from the notification table that don't exists in the notification_seen table for the specified user.

I didn't try, but it should work.

```
public function getUnreadNotifications(User $user)
{
    // Create query builder
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');

    // someone saw the notification
    $nobodySawIt = $qb->expr()->eq('SIZE(n.seenBy)', 0);

    // Create expression for 'another guy saw the notification, but not my user'
    $someOneElseSawIt = $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->neq('SIZE(n.seenBy)', 0), // someone saw the notification
        $qb->expr()->neq('u.id', $user->getId()) // but not this user
    );

    // Create the query
    $qb
        ->leftJoin('n.seenBy', 's') // Join on NotificationSeen
        ->leftJoin('s.user', 'u') // Join on User
        ->orWhere($nobodySawIt) // I want unread notifications
        ->orWhere($someOneElseSawIt); // and notifications that this guys didn't read yet
      /*
        ->addOrderBy(alias.property)
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
       */

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Tell me if something's wrong